# C:\Progra~2 not working in OEM Version of Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch-file

I am working on creating a batch file in Windows 8, which won't accept `"C:\Program files"` in its body because the space between *Program* and *files* gives an error. So, I used `"C:\Progra~2"`.

I want to access `Program files (x86)`.

I have two Windows 8 PC's: Windows 8 PRO and Windows 8 OEM.

When I type `"C:\Progra~2"` from File Explorer to access `program files (x86)` it opens successfully in Windows 8 PRO.

But when I do the same in Windows 8 OEM, it says

> Windows cannot find C:\Progra~2.

I am not sure whether this is an issue with the PRO and OEM versions.

Can anyone help me find the solution?

Comment: The olden DOS 8.3 short name mapping is unpredictable.  You almost surely got into this trouble by forgetting to use double quotes around the file name.  Necessary to ensure that the embedded space in the directory name doesn't cause trouble.  You'll still need them when you use the environment variable properly.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example for windows 8. In batch file am using C:\Progra~2\Applicationname\Service.exe -s

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Application name\Service.exe" -s`  <-- this should work.

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks

Answer (score 5):

Use a batch built in Constant: %ProgramFiles%. It also works on non-englisch windows Version, which your ~2 does not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are two program files on both machines? Try `C:\Progra~1` and see if that opens the right folder.

If you want to open a general programs file folder use `%ProgramFiles%`

Comment: yes i have program files and program files (x86) in both machines. Even C:\Program-1 is not working in OEM pc

Comment: You can do `DIR c:\ /ad /x` to see what short filename the folder has.